# Building random homeomorphisms of the torus $\mathbb T^2$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, gr.group-theory, measure-theory, ds.dynamical-systems

In https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.3423, a family of random homeomorphisms of the circle is constructed. **Main Question:** *Can the construction be generalized to higher space dimensions, e.g. to $\mathbb T^2$?*

**Further details:** How can one use such construction to build a measure on the group of homeomorphisms of $\mathbb T^2$?  I would like these properties to hold for the measure: (1) A measure zero set has empty interior; (2) Every subset of a measure zero set has measure zero too; (3) Countable union of measure zero sets has measure zero too; (4) quasi-invariance in some sense. See [A measure on the group of homeomorphisms of $\mathbb T^2$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429799/a-measure-on-the-group-of-homeomorphisms-of-mathbb-t2) for this question specifically.

**Further context:** Given a positive Borel measure without atoms $\tau$ on the circle $\mathbb T =\mathbb R /\mathbb Z =[0,1)$, in https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.3423 a  homeomorphism  $h:[0,1)\to [0,1)$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
h(t)=\tau ([0,t))/\tau ([0,1) )%\qquad \mbox{for}\;\; \theta\in [0,1)
\label{h1}
\end{equation}
Specifically they take $\tau$ formally proportional to $ e^{\beta X(t)}dt$ where
$\beta\geq 0$ and  $X$
is the Gaussian Free Field on the circle
i.e. the random field $X$  with covariance $\mathbb E\, X(t)X(t')=-\log |e^{2\pi it}-e^{2\pi it'}|$ (see within the link and https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.1003 for all the rigorous details).

Comment: Just consider the "product" $(x,y)\mapsto (f(x),g(y))$ of two such "random" homeomorphisms. You need to require something on the resulting probability measure on Homeo of the torus to make the question nontrivial.

Comment: @YCor That's actually another question that i have: how does one use these random homeomorphisms to build a measure on Homeo? For such measure, ideally, I would like these properties to hold:  (1) A measure zero set has empty interior; (2) Every subset of a measure zero set has measure zero too; (3) 
Countable union of measure zero sets has measure zero too; (4) quasi-invariance in some sense

Comment: @user490373 Their motivation seems to be to exhibit a family of homeomorphisms for which the welding problem has an (essentially) unique solution and to (heuristically) link them to SLE. Neither of these has a higher-dimensional analogue as far as I know.

Comment: @MartinHairer I see, thanks. Actually, I'm only interested in building a measure on the group of homeomorphisms of the torus $\mathbb T^2$ and generalizing that work was the first idea that came to mind. But do you see an alternative option to build such measure? Ideally, it should satisfy the following properties: (1) A measure zero set has empty interior; (2) Every subset of a measure zero set has measure zero too; (3) Countable union of measure zero sets has measure zero too; (4) quasi-invariance in some sense

Comment: I conjecture that if you compose many random translations with random homeomorphisms whose support is a small neighborhood of the identity, this composition will converge in distribution to something like a normal distribution on homeomorphisms. You can test whether this version of the central limit theorem is plausible using the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test on some (one real) invariant of your random homeomorphism.

Comment: @JosephVanName I cannot quite follow the comment. Could you elaborate more on the details and possibly post it as an answer?