# A measure on the group of homeomorphisms of $\mathbb T^2$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, gr.group-theory, measure-theory, ds.dynamical-systems

Let us consider the group of measure-preserving homeomorphisms of $\mathbb T^2$ (with transformations identified if they agree almost
everywhere) called $G[\mathbb T^2, \mathcal L^2]$. We shall consider on it the following strong topology: a map $T_{j}$ converges to $T$ in $G[\mathbb T^2, \mathcal L^2]$ if $T_{j}$ and $T_{j}^{-1}$ converge uniformly on $\mathbb T^2$ to $T$ and $T^{-1}$.

How can we build a measure on this group that has the following property?

(1) A measure zero set has empty interior;

(2) Every subset of a measure zero set has measure zero too;

(3) Countable union of measure zero sets has measure zero too;

(4) quasi-invariance in some sense

Point (4) is deliberately a bit vague. The question is motivated by the related [Building random homeomorphisms of the torus $\mathbb T^2$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429741/building-random-homeomorphisms-of-the-torus-mathbb-t2)

Comment: Which topology are you putting on your group, and which sigma algebra are you choosing to define your measure on?

Comment: @YemonChoi Added: we shall consider the following topology: a map $T_{j}$ converges to $T$ in $G[\mathbb T^2, \mathcal L^2]$ if $T_{j}$ and $T_{j}^{-1}$ converge uniformly on $\mathbb T^2$ to $T$ and $T^{-1}$.

Comment: @YemonChoi For the measure to be constructed on the group, I don't know -- whichever one is more convenient for the desired properties to hold.